# How to add a FloatingActionButton to the toolbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, toolbar, floating-action-button

**Problem:**
I need to add two FAB of that [implementation](https://github.com/JorgeCastilloPrz/FABProgressCircle/tree/master/app/src/main/res/values) to the toolbar. 
Having both buttons on the bottom-right-corner seems to take too much of the screen's space.

**Question:**
How can I add a FloatingActionButton to the Toolbar?

Comment: do you want to add FloatingActionButton or FloatingActionButton with progress?

Comment: floating action button with progress - the progress indicator of the action button is the reason why I want it. If a usual button would be enough I would add a simple item to the menu

Comment: try to create custom layout for toolbar

Answer (score 0):

All of the elements on your question are a simple `View`. ALL of them!

That means that, all you have to do is just build the layout with the views on the places you want them to be. Just like you would with LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ImageView, TextView, etc.

The specific implementation will vary on what you actually want to look like exactly. But probably something like the following pseudo-XML should get you started.

```
<LinearLayout orientation=vertical>

   <AppBarLayout>
      <Toolbar />

      <com.github.jorgecastilloprz.FABProgressCircle>
         <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton />
      </com.github.jorgecastilloprz.FABProgressCircle>
   </AppBarLayout>

   <FrameLayout height=match_parent>
        ... your app content comes here
   </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```